# What is direct/organic in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm seeing lots of traffic in the source / medium report showing direct / organic.

My searching isn't turning up any answers as to how that's possible, given that direct means Google Google can't discern the source, how do they know it was organic?

[image]

Comment: Show a screenshot please

Comment: @MichelePisani I've edited the question, it's row 6 in the linked screenshot.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't programming related. It might be on-topic for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Quentin that's ok, I'll go there for future GA questions. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From your screenshot I see another strange `source / medium` as well `direct / organic` that is `organic / facebook`, however since there are many custom `source / medium` I believe that it inserted with an UTM, like this:

```
yourdomain.com?utm_source=direct&utm_medium=organic
```

Check if you have a campaign name with second dimensions in the report. However it is it is likely that there is a link with those parameters that sends to your site.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I don't have the reputation for my upvote to show but it's there.